# jQuery Year Picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have one form in that I have Year of passed out field for that I need to show only years drop down.

Is it possible to show only years in jQuery datepicker?? Otherwise is there any angular directive to show only years in drop down?

```
$("#date").datepicker({
  changeMonth: false,
  changeYear: true,
  dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
  duration: 'fast',
  stepMonths: 0
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LttVe/628/

Comment: If you want year dropdown, why not create a normal select element with ng-repeat?

Comment: take a look at this https://plnkr.co/edit/ngefLrIH4MHeclY3Y7XD?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in comments, why not to create a simple dropdown if only years need to be selected. Following is an example to create a directive for that.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.details = { year_of_completion: null, year_of_admission: null }
}).directive('yearPicker', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      ngModel: '=',
      startYear: '@',
      totalYears: '@'
    },
    template: '<select ng-model="ngModel" ng-options="year for year in yearsRange"></select>',
    link: function(scope) {
      scope.yearsRange = [];
      for (var i = 0; i <= scope.totalYears; i++) {
        scope.yearsRange.push(scope.startYear++)
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <year-picker ng-model="details.year_of_admission" start-year="1997" total-years="20"></year-picker>
    Admission year: {{details.year_of_admission}}
    <br />
    <year-picker ng-model="details.year_of_completion" start-year="1997" total-years="20"></year-picker>
    Submission year: {{details.year_of_completion}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this in my input model `ng-model="details.year_of_completion"`.for this how can I bind years?

Comment: How Can I use this for more than one ng-model

Comment: An input can have only one `ng-model`. Can you please elaborate what do you want to achieve.

Comment: I have two different `ng-models`, am trying to use this directive for both `models`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160680/discussion-between-vipin-kumar-and-krish).

Answer (score 1):

Okay this is a bit of a hack..with CSS (If you add this it removes the calendar section)
Also if you need to apply it to only a particular datepicker,enclosed in a div, add a class and then use this with that class.

```
.ui-datepicker-calendar {
       display: none;
    }
    .ui-datepicker-month {
       display: none;
    }
    .ui-datepicker-prev{
       display: none;
    }
    .ui-datepicker-next{
       display: none;
    }
```

Edit:

```
$("#date").datepicker({
  changeMonth: false,
  changeYear: true,
  dateFormat: 'yy',
  duration: 'fast',
  stepMonths: 0,
  onChangeMonthYear: function (e) {
    console.log(e);
        $("#date").val(e);
        $('.ui-datepicker').css("display","none").blur();
  }
});
```

Use the `onChangeMonthYear` event, in `e` we are getting the selected year.
You just need to set in the text and hide the datepicker.

Comment: @krish Yea,,checking that!